# thread class doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

relates to threads and parallel programming

i saw a question on thread which was answered by someone .i tried the code answered by him and wrote it.
i tried

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <thread>
   using namespace std;
   void printx()
   {
    cout << "Hello world!!!!"<< endl;
    cout << "Hello world!!!!"<< endl; 
    cout << "Hello world!!!!"<< endl; 
    cout << "Hello world!!!!"<< endl;  
   }
   int main(){
    cout << "Hello world!!!!"<< endl; 
    thread t1(printx);
    //t1.join();
    t1.detach();
    cout << "Hello world!!!!"<< endl; 
   t1.join();
   return 0;
   }
```

and i received output as

Hello world!!!!

that was printed only once
i don't understand
shouldn't it be more number of times

Comment: Printing the same string is not very good way to debug, Print out different string and check the control flow of the code. check which part is not executing.

Comment: As @JayJoshi pointed out in his answer, threads once detached cannot be joined. Find relevant documentation on threads here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand some basic concepts for thread:

> **thread.detach( )** 
>  Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits.

Two threads are 'Joinable' if they both have same `thread id`. And It becomes 'NOT Joinable' once you called `join` method or `detach` method.!

#### Problem

You called `thread.detach()` first, which will separate the thread from main thread. And then You are again trying to `join` it which will give Error because two threads can not be joined as they are separated and have different `thread id`.

#### Solution

Either use `join` or use `detach`. Don't use both of them.

1. **Join**
   The function returns when the thread execution has completed.

   ```
     void printx()
      {
        cout << "In thread"<< endl;
      }
     int main()
     {
       cout << "Before thread"<< endl; 
       thread t1(printx);
       t1.join();
       cout << "After Thread"<< endl; 
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **Detach**
   separates out the execution of both threads.

   ```
   void printx()
   {
       cout << "In thread"<< endl;
   }
   int main()
   {
       cout << "Before thread"<< endl; 
       thread t1(printx);
       t1.detach();
       cout << "After Thread"<< endl; 
       return 0;
   }
   ```

References:

- [Join](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/)
- [detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach)

Comment: thank you for the answer but i think that a wrong code was printed by me .otherwise there would have been an error.Still removing that line would do same output. I found a solution :::: dev c++ requires additional files for right output. so i installed codeblocks and output were as expected.